# Gravity form Change value of quantity based on previous field selection

Tags: gravityforms

Hi I am using Gravity Form, and I am trying to build a form where depending on the service you choose, the quantity of hours will update automatically. For example:

Multiple choice field: 1. Wash a car 2. wash a truck 3. wash a motorbike

Quantity field should pre-populate with either; 1 (if motorbike is selected, or 2 (if car is selected or 3 (if truck is selected)

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generous developer I know helped me out. Add this code after the form. here is the answer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var helpSelect = document.querySelector('#input_2_22')
var quantityInput = document.querySelector('#input_2_28')
helpSelect.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
quantityInput.value = e.target.value
})
</script>
```

Remember to change the input id to the id of the input in your form.